# Magento Custom Options - add a CSS className to the custom option in dropdown

Tags: php, magento

I want to specify a CSS class to apply to my custom options. This will allow me to use more robust JavaScript selectors on the product view page.

I have tried a lot but not getting how to add.

[image]

For this i am trying to change in Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\select.php

and following line is adding this options

```
$select->addOption(
                    $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
                    $_value->getTitle() . ' ' . $priceStr . '',
                    array('price' => $this->helper('core')->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false)),
                    array('class' => 'testsfs')
                );
```

But not getting how i can add my custom class to this option.
I hope someone help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution. 
Only need to add 'class' => 'myClass' in array.

```
$select->addOption(
                    $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
                    $_value->getTitle() . ' ' . $priceStr . '',
                    array('price' => $this->helper('core')->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false), 'class' => 'myClass')
                );
```